# Can we insert and truncate partitions parallely?

Tags: database, indexing, sybase, database-partitioning, partition

I have a large partitioned table with local indexes created on it and there are mulitple threads perform 2 operations on this table these are..

1. truncate the existing partition
2. insert into partition

`Thread-1 will operate on parition-1
 Thread-2 will operate on parition-2
 and so on...`

My Question is

In a situation where threads 1,2,3,4 completes truncating the partition 1,2,3,4 `(thread-1 will operate on partition-1 and so on)` and started insert operation.  At the same time thread-5 will try to truncate the partition-5 and it is failing.

Can anyone tell me what did i missed here?

Comment: failed with what error? Which DB? ASA, IQ or ASE?

Comment: @Meet **SYBASE ASE**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing i missed to mentioned here is **indexes**

if we have global clustered index across partition it will not work. i removed the global index and it's working now. thanks